# Link to FB profile picture remotely or store it locally?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

I've built my own blog with Facebook login. Currently, I'm using the following to show my FB user's profile picture at the top of the blog, to show they are signed in:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/[profileID]/picture">
```

Now I want to add profile pictures to each and every comment left on a blog article, and there are 20 comments per page. This means there are 21 requests going to FB for profile pics. Is this a good idea or should I be grabbing the profile picture from FB (programatically of course) and storing it locally?

I know how to grab the picture if I need to, I just want to know if what I'm doing is right or wrong? Very occasionally, I notice a little lag just loading one profile picture from FB, I'm concerned about loading 20 different ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pros of using FB:

1. You don't waste your space
2. You don't waste your traffic
3. You don't waste your webserver connections/CPU/IO
4. You always have actual userpics on your page
5. FB has better CDN than you do
6. Each browser limits simultaneous HTTP requests per domain. So having different hosts (at least your one and FB one) could potentially improve page loading speed.

Cons of using FB:

1. If your app is an intranet one - FB would consume your users' internet traffic

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll leave it as it is then. One question about number 5, "FB has better CDN than you do", I don't understand that. Surely loading an image from my server, where my website is located, will be faster than loading it remotely from FB, no?

Comment: @PaparazzoKid: "Surely loading an image from my server, where my website is located, will be faster " --- why do you think so? FB's CDN has servers all over the world and nearest will be chosen to serve the image. And likely it will be closer to the user than yours

Answer (score -2):

OK this question is purely about which approach is better. I will not advise you to locally save profile pictures as user may change picture on their profile and you will end up with added responsibility of updating them.

More over once the picture is loaded from FB then for next 20 pictures browser will be using the cached image rather then making fresh requests to FB Server.

Hope it make sense

Thanks

Kaushik

Comment: How is the browser supposed to cache 20 images from 20 different profile ID's... I didn't think so! 20 comments are NOT all from the same user. Also, the responsibility of updating a profile picture is no problem at all for me, I'll do it back-end once-a-week or something, or when they next login.

Comment: OK I missed the point that comments from different user. My Fault. I think the profile pics will be thumbnails. if that the case loading all those pics from FB should not be problem....